# creating nested dictionary from list of dictionary

Tags: python

i have dictionary dictionary like bellow (parsed lspci info)

original dictionary:

```
d={'host':{'v':'v1','d':'d1','sv':'sv1','sd':'sd1'},
    'ether':{'v':'v2','d':'d2','sv':'sv2','sd':'sd2'}}
```

dictionary to check with original dictionary:

```
to_check={'host':['v','d'],'ether':['v','d','sv']}
```

i need output like this

```
output_dict={'host':{'v':'v1','d':'d1'},'ether':{'v':'v2','d':'d2','sv':'sv2'}}
```

How do i achieve using dict comprehension ??
is there another easy way

Comment: Another easy way beside what?

Answer (score 5):

```
print {k:{key:d[k][key] for key in to_check[k] if key in d[k]} for k in to_check}
```

**Output**

```
{'ether': {'d': 'd2', 'v': 'v2', 'sv': 'sv2'}, 'host': {'d': 'd1', 'v': 'v1'}}
```

Comment: Haha. Haha. Quick, dammit. +1.

Comment: Your comprehension fu is off the charts :P

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> {k:{v:d[k][v] for v in vs} for k,vs in to_check.items()}
{'ether': {'d': 'd2', 'sv': 'sv2', 'v': 'v2'}, 'host': {'d': 'd1', 'v': 'v1'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> {key: {l: d.get(key).get(l) for l in lst} for key, lst in to_check.items()}
{'host': {'d': 'd1', 'v': 'v1'}, 'ether': {'sv': 'sv2', 'd': 'd2', 'v': 'v2'}}
```

It is safer to use `get` as opposed to `[]` because it gives you more flexibility, for example if the key `x` is not present (I just added this to `to_check`), then you can set another value in `get` to give you a default value:

```
>>> {key: {l: d.get(key, 'Does Not Exist').get(l, 'Does Not exit') for l in lst} for key, lst in to_check.items()}
{'host': {'x': 'Does Not exit', 'd': 'd1', 'v': 'v1'}, 'ether': {'sv': 'sv2', 'd': 'd2', 'v': 'v2'}}
```